# How to grep (print only) lines starting with uppercase-lowercase pattern?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a command that prints lines in format "Name:nickname". But since it is an output from getent, it also contains some lines which are not names.

However, they all are either only uppercase or only lowercase, whereas "real" names start with one uppercase letter and one lowercase letter.

I copied this command to print only lines starting with uppercase:

```
... | grep -P '^[^\s]+\s+[A-Z]'
```

Now, how should I extend the command so it checks the second letter as well and prints the line only if it is lowercase?

Answer (score 3):

You can match lines that start with an upper-case letter followed by at least one lower-case letter using POSIX brackets:

```
... | grep '^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]'
```

This doesn't need PCRE (`-P`) or even extended (`-E`) regular expression support.

Comment: thanks a lot for an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in your example RegEx `'^[^\s]+\s+[A-Z]'` *( although it is not correctly formatted )* that you are trying to capture even those lines that start with empty space before the actual names. If I am right then you can use the RegEx `'(^[\s]+[A-Z][a-z]+)|(^[A-Z][a-z]+)'` in your `grep` command like so:

```
... | grep -P '(^[\s]+[A-Z][a-z]+)|(^[A-Z][a-z]+)'
```

This will output all the lines that start with an upper case letter followed by any number of lower case letters in the first word even if it is preceded with any number of white spaces in the same line.

---

**Explanation**:

This matches any of the two groups contained in each `()` and separated by the or operator `|`.

- `^` will start at the beginning of the line.
- `[\s]` will match any white-space character (spaces, tabs, line breaks).
- `+` will match 1 or more of the preceding character set.
- `[A-Z]` will match one upper case letter.
- `[a-z]+` will match one or more lower case letter.

---

**Notice**:

You might want to delete the preceding space in the output lines. In this case pipe the output to a tool like `sed` and use it with `sed 's/^ *//'` where `^ *` will start at the beginning of the line and match one or more continuous spaces then it will be deleted. Use it like so:

```
... | grep -P '(^[\s]+[A-Z][a-z]+)|(^[A-Z][a-z]+)' | sed 's/^ *//'
```